# How to get the index of an node element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to get the index of a p tag so that when the user clicks on it the p tag will either change color or text size(maybe both). I am using reactjs, but I am trying to do it in jquery. I gave every p tag a data and name attribute. Here is my code. How do I make it so only the clicked element gets a css change so the user knows it is selected. The function running the p tags is in the HTML showChapters function.

```js
$(onReady)


function onReady() {

    $("#voteSearchInput").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });//end of voteSearchInput

    $('#root').on('click', '.bookChapters' ,() => {
        console.log('clicked')

        //I want to change the color here 
        
        
    });

}//end of onReady
```

```html
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './Header.jsx';
import axios from 'axios';


class Book extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            book:Object,
            user:Object,
            chapters:[],
            chapterCount:0,
            ready:false,
        };//end of state

    }//end of constructor

    start() {
        console.log(this.state.book)
    }


    showChapters() {
        let chapterCount = this.state.chapterCount;
        let chapters = this.state.book.length;
        let chatpersArr = this.state.chapters;

        
        for(let i = 0; i < chapters; i++) {
            chatpersArr.push([])
        }
        
        
        return (
            chatpersArr.map((ch, id) => {
                chapterCount++;
                return (
                    <p key={id} className='bookChapters' data-index={id}>{this.state.book.book} Chapter:{chapterCount}</p>
                )
            })
        )
    }//end start

    componentWillMount() {
        //Always gettting the last book out of the array
        

        //AUTHENTICATES THE USER
        axios.get('/login').then(res => {
            let userInfo = res.data;
            if(userInfo === "Not Authenticated") {
                window.location = "/?#/";
            } 
        });//end of axios GET

        //GETS THE CORRECT BOOK FROM THE REDUCER
        if(this.props.book.editBookReducer.length - 1 === -1) {
            window.location = "/?#/user";
        }
        else {
            let lastBook = this.props.book.editBookReducer.length -1;
            let book = this.props.book.editBookReducer[lastBook].data.book;
            let user = this.props.book.editBookReducer[lastBook].data.user;
            this.setState({book, user, ready:true});
        }
    }//end componentWillMount


    render() {

        if(!this.state.ready){
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div>
                <Header/>
                <button onClick={this.start.bind(this)} >start</button>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row" style={{"textAlign": "center"}}>
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <h1>{this.state.book.book}</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row" style={{"textAlign": "center"}}>
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                {this.showChapters()}
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <textarea name="" id="" cols="50" rows="60"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }

        
    }
}//end class Book


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        
    },
     dispatch)
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        book:state
    }
}




export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Book);
```

Comment: `"I am using reactjs, but I am trying to do it in jquery."` Why's that? You don't need to use jquery when developing with React.js

Comment: How would you do it in just reactjs?

Comment: I would also recommend doing it in React. But if you really want to do it in jQuery, don't use the arrow function in the click handler, then `this` will be the element you clicked on, so you could theoretically target it and change its properties directly.

Answer (score 0):

React has event handling system built in that you can leverage. For more info [see the docs.](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Here I assign an `onClick` to the `p` element and use the `data-index` that you defined.

```
class Book extends React.Component {

  handleChapterClicked = (event) => {
    // you can get the index like this
    let pIndex = event.target.getAttribute("data-index");
    // your logic for the handler here
  }

  showChapters() {
    let chapterCount = this.state.chapterCount;
    let chapters = this.state.book.length;
    let chatpersArr = this.state.chapters;


    for(let i = 0; i < chapters; i++) {
        chatpersArr.push([])
    }


    return (
        chatpersArr.map((ch, id) => {
            chapterCount++;
            return (
                <p key={id} className='bookChapters' onClick={this.handleChapterClicked} data-index={id}>{this.state.book.book} Chapter:{chapterCount}</p>
            )
        })
    )
  }//end start
}
```

---

You can get rid of the `data-index` attribute and bind the index to be the first argument that is passed to `handleChapterClicked`:

```
<p key={id} className='bookChapters' onClick={this.handleChapterClicked.bind(this, id)} data-index={id}>{this.state.book.book} Chapter:{chapterCount}</p>
```

And then the definition of the function would be changed to be:

```
handleChapterClicked = (index, event) => {
    // your logic for the handler here
}
```